# Readline() in a loop is not working in python

Tags: python, readline

I have a file called `file` with this text:

```
Hello
I am not a bot
I am a human
Do you believe me?
I know you won't
Yes I am a bot
Yes you thought it right
```

This code prints out all the lines of the text:

```
with open(file) as f:
    for i in f:
        print(i,end="")
```

But this code does not, and I don't understand why.

```
with open(file) as f:
    for i in f:
        print(f.readline(),end="")
```

This prints out:

```
I am not a bot
Do you believe me?
Yes I am a bot
```

What I understand is as the loop goes over the lines in the file, it will read that line and return that as a string which is then printed.
If I replace the for loop with `for i in range(9)`, it works.

Comment: Why are you mixing iteration *over the file object* and readline calls? Iterating *already reads the lines*.

Comment: Yeah, but why does putting readline() there does not work?

Comment: It does work. You can see that it reads three of the lines in your file, just as you asked it to. (the fact that it doesn't read the lines already consumed by `i`, is not `readline`'s fault)

Comment: Oh, I see. So readline() can't use it when i has the line consumed.
Thanks :)

Comment: I often use the `splitline()` method that returns the lines in a list (i.e. `data_lines = f.read().splitline()` )

Comment: Upvoting; I'm not sure it's fair to equate "failure to understand file iteration" with "lack of research".

Comment: Sarcasm?;I researched but couldn't find any topic relevant to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the for loop over the file object calls implicitly to `readline` (or equivalent)
so what is happend is that in each loop you call `readline` twice, and this is why you get every second line